# Using source command to replace bash string with field array

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, source

I've programmed in other languages but bash and unix in general are very new to me. I think a bash wizard might see an obvious solution, using the source command to read in a settings file - and assign values to my command string?

Ideally I'd like to create a command string from all the field/value settings in a file, by replacing their matches in a string.

My file will look something like:

**settings.cfg**

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# WiFi Settings
#
wifi_name=mywifiname
wifi_password=wifi-pwd
#
# Icecast Server Settings
#
icecast_server=icecast.domain.com
icecast_port=443
icecast_mount_url=/user/99999/show/0123456
icecast_show=RPi Demo Show
icecast_user=
icecast_password=icecast-pwd
#
# avconv setting for Raspbian Jessie Lite
# may not need if you're using a self compiled ffmpeg version
#
icecast_legacy=1
#
# Stream Settings - probably not safer to go higher unless great internet connection
#
stream_bitrate=128k
```

So if I used command:

```
source settings.cfg
```

There would be a variable named `$stream_bitrate` that would have the value of "128k".

I could then use a string replace on `stream_parameters= <stream_bitrate>` to make that look like `stream_parameters= 128k`

But I'm wondering if bash gurus can see a simple index based loop - or regular expression that might do the job for whatever parameters are loaded.

I can change my settings file to make it easier if needed. I've put "<>" around the replacement parameter locations - but those can be removed or modified if needed.

And it can be one command line string if needed.

> **EDIT:** Move command line processing to second file

Would this work?

**ProcessSettings.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Load in config file settings
source settings.cfg

# build command line string
start_cmd=avconv -re -i test.mp3 -c:a libmp3lame -ac 2 -ar 44100 -content_type audio/mpeg -b:a
stream_parameters="$stream_bitrate -f mp3 -ice_name "$icecast_show" -password "icecast_password" -legacy_icecast $icecast_legacy"
icecast_setup=icecast://$icecast_user:$icecast_password@$icecast_server:$icecast_port$icecast_mount_url

stream_cmd = "$start_cmd $stream_parameters $icecast_setup"
```

Comment: Why not just let the shell dereference the variable? I.e. `stream_parameters= $stream_bitrate`

Comment: So is that the best solution - just rebuild the string inline with the parameters? No loop necessary?

Comment: I mean, why overcomplicate things?

Comment: Okay - so I would  do that in a second bash file that includes the last three lines/strings - the second file would then do the source command and build the command string and continue on. Keep it simple.

Comment: I don't think you'd even need a second script. Just put the variables that have spaces into quotes, like `stream_parameters="$stream_bitrate -f mp3 -ice_name $icecast_show -password $icecast_password -legacy_icecast $icecast_legacy"`

Comment: The shell will deref the little vars inside the big var as long as the little vars have been declared first. "little" and "big" have no technical significance, btw.

Comment: I was thinking I'd be getting the cfg file from a different location - so would use source (in a second file)  to process it quickly (see updated question)

Comment: I'll write you an answer so we can hopefully mark this resolved.

Comment: Sure - thanks. And if you modify my last line `$stream_cmd` - it's probably a simple question - but not sure how I would execute the command in the string. Is there something that allows me to run a program defined by a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script in your edit should work perfectly.

But you should note that Bash's variable declaration is picky. I rewrote your code:

```
# Strings with spaces must be quoted, or the shell will think the second word is a command (-re, in this case).
start_cmd="avconv -re -i test.mp3 -c:a libmp3lame -ac 2 -ar 44100 -content_type audio/mpeg -b:a"

# You can't nest quotes. A quote mark terminates the quotation, unless it's escaped.
stream_parameters="$stream_bitrate -f mp3 -ice_name $icecast_show -password $icecast_password -legacy_icecast $icecast_legacy" 

# It's best to quote strings, as a habit.
icecast_setup="icecast://$icecast_user:$icecast_password@$icecast_server:$icecast_port$icecast_mount_url"

# Don't put spaces around the equals sign.
stream_cmd="$start_cmd $stream_parameters $icecast_setup"
```

As for how to run a command defined by a string, it's super simple. Just run this: `$stream_cmd`

Also you might want to state the absolute path of the config file (maybe `~/settings.cfg`), unless you want to use the relative location.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback. I'm learning something every day here.

Comment: Happy to help !

Comment: You might find http://shellcheck.net useful. It can check your code, just like I've done here.

Comment: Thanks! I will do that for sure. Just uploaded some more bash and udev rules to Code Review for feedback. That's the code for the first step - this here is my second step. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/133736/bash-scripts-and-udev-rules-to-handle-usb-auto-mounting-unmounting